# Can you insert anything other than a variable in {curly braces} of an f string literal?

Tags: python, string, oop, f-string

I was writing a print statement to test code.
But I realised I mistakenly had put a (self-defined) object (from a different class) in the {}.

I have already add the **str** method in the object to be able to call off print on it.

I tried to see if {print(thatobject)} would give me something.

When it didn't, I tried to read the document to understand what are the valid inputs for the {curly braces}. But couldn't understand it

Can someone explain what would be the valid inputs for the {curly braces} in a f string literal.

**Excuse me for using ppor terminology and just calling them "inputs". I hope you get what I mean (Variables, Function outputs, etc)

***I am aware that methods like len() can also be inserted in the {}.

```
class Player:
    
    def __init__(self,name):
        
        self.name = name
        self.all_cards = []
        
    def add_cards(self,new_cards):
        '''
        Will be able to add multiple cards or just a single
        '''        
        if type(new_cards) == list:
            self.all_cards.extend(new_cards)
        else: 
            self.all_cards.append(new_cards)
       
    
    def remove_one(self):
        pass
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Player {self.name} has {len(self.all_cards)} cards. They are {print(self.all_cards)}"
```

Comment: Any expression can be put within `{}`. `print()` returns `None` so the expression within the curly braces results in `None` as well. In this case, you don't need the `print`

Comment: Seems like you already answered your own question. Calling len() is no different than print() since it's just a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in f-string's {curly braces} you can use any variables, class objects, executable expressions, function callings, etc. Anything can be used in brackets. You saw `None` on `{print(self.all_cards)}` because print function only returns `None` in python. If you want to print all_cards only remove that  `print` method from it. Use like this `{self.all_cards}`.
As you can read on the [official docs](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python). Everything inside the {brackets} is expressions that are evaluated at runtime and then formatted to that string.
And if we elaborate your f-string working:

```
    return f"Player {self.name} has {len(self.all_cards)} cards. They are {print(self.all_cards)}"
```

it will execute `{self.name}` get the variable value place it in that position, `len(self.all_cards)` len method is being executed and return the length of the `self.all_cards` list, `{print(self.all_cards)}` it will execute print method which only returned None.
And f-string will return like this after execution and formatting:

```
Player test has 0 cards. They are None
```